# returning values of function in python

Tags: python, function

Why do I have to return function in the else case? Can't I just apply the defined function because I have to only return the value of b and store it?

```
def gcd_a(a,b):

    if a==0:
        return b
    else:
        gcd_a(b%a,a)
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here? You're recursively calling `gcd_a`. After Python finishes the recursive call, shouldn't `gcd_a` return something?

Comment: You are not returning anything in the else case.

Comment: You are not returning the function in `else` case but you are just calling it recursively. And please try to elaborate your problem.

Comment: There is no difference in behavior when you call a function from within itself, there is no "special case".  You need to have it behave the same way you would have a non-recursive function behave, i.e, all control paths should return a value if the function is supposed to return a value.

Comment: I just wanted to know that at the end only the ''if" case will work so I'm returning that , won't it suffice?

Answer (score 3):

I think the main concept you are missing is that in order to get the result of a recursive function (or any function for that matter), *the function that you access the result of must return the value**

Right now, when you call `gcd_a`, a recursive call to `gcd_a` will *eventually* return a value, however it will be lost, since the function that you are accessing the result of does not return a value.

To show you this is true, let's add in a log statement that prints when the function is returning:

```
def gcd_a(a,b):
    if a==0:
      print('finally returning!', b)
      return b
    else:
        gcd_a(b%a,a)
```

Now if we call:

```
print(gcd_a(10, 99))
```

We get the following output:

```
finally returning! 1
None
```

Somewhere, a recursive call to `gcd_a` found your condition to be `True`, and returned `1`, however, this result is not printed, because it is not returned by your call to `gcd_a`

---

<sub>* Unless you do something strange like updating a global variable, etc...</sub>

Comment: but afterall I just need to return value of 'b' only , I need only value of 'b' that's why I just returned that , why does it prints None then?the last value that needs to be returned is b and not gcd_a(b%a,a)

Comment: Because the call to gcd_a that returns b is not the call that you are accessing the result of.

Comment: I'm accessing value(result) of 'b' at the end right?

Answer (score 1):

In the else block, if you don't return the function call, the outer function returns `None` because python interpreter just runs whatever is returned by the gcd function.

Let's assume the following code:

```
def func():
    10
```

In that function, it just runs `10`, but it doesn't mean that there is some return from the function.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the problem is in the way you are thinking about *function* which has to be cleared. The fact that you are having this doubt in a *recursive* function call is incidental because you are calling the same function again and again with different arguments causing different branches to be executed.

How will a function that doesn't `return` anything in **any** of its **branches** be helpful to its `caller`? In your case, what would happen if your function's `caller` calls it with an argument that hits your `else` block? It will return nothing and this won't help the `caller`!

Now in your recursive case, if your `caller` calls the function with an argument that hits the `if` block, then it would work as expected. However, if it hits the `else` block, then it would become a caller and call the same function again. For simplicity, let us assume that this time it hits the `if` condition and returns something to its caller. However, will that reach the **original** `caller` that initiated everything? The answer is no because you are not returning it to him!

Most of the times you would need a `return` for every branch in a function 
 unless you are doing it on purpose for a side effect.

Answer (score 1):

If your function finishes without returning anything, it will implicitly return `None`.

```
def double(val):
   val * 2

value = double(10)
print(value)
```

Which is fine, except it doesn't have a return statement, and so all you get is `None`

The same applies to recursive functions: you can do all the recursive function calls you want, but if you don't actually return the result of the function, then it'll return `None`.